# Set java entrypoint to a class that's in a JAR inside another JAR

Tags: java, entry-point

I have a JAR that's packaged with One Jar, so it contains multiple dependencies inside itself(using the JAR URL notation):

```
<one.jar>!/lib/<deps1.jar>
<one.jar>!/lib/<deps2.jar>
...
```

Is it possible to run `main()` from a class `com.example.A` that lives in `deps2.jar`?

I tried `java -cp one.jar!/lib/deps2.jar com.example.A`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Using Maven shade plugin you can create a fat jar and define the main class to run inside Manifest.MF file.

Comment: Did you check http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=details&file=manifest?

Comment: As long as `one.jar` depends on the nested jar, loading it should also make that jar's classes available, thus `java -cp one.jar com.example.A` should work fine. Or are you trying to *exclude* `one.jar` from the classpath?

Comment: @Izruo I guess the problem comes from packaing with OneJar. It includes a special custom loader for stuff that's inside the final jar and the dependencies are not exported through manifest

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing yes I have, I don't see how that helps me. I can run the main application, that's not the problem, I want to run one main() method from one of the dependencies.

Comment: @Sambit I'm not using Maven shade, I'm using One Jar. I can't switch. This is not a question about a workaround, this is a question about that specific case.

Comment: Can you just include a main() somewhere in the primary .jar that delegates to com.example.A.main()? ... or is this all about a .jar you aren't able to build yourself?

Comment: @Steve yep, I thankfully can, that's what I ended up doing currently as  I can't find another way. The behavior of this program depends on the packaging, so it's crucial that it runs "as-in-the-final-distribution" form. Was just hoping for a quick way to launch things.

Comment: Glad this worked for you without much fuss.  I added the idea as an answer to round out this question/answer in S.O.  Please press the checkmark to show that this was the best answer to your question.  I honestly don't care about the points so much as having this particular S.O. question be complete and answered. - and if I didn't represent your chosen solution correctly, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include a main() somewhere in your primary .jar that delegates to com.example.A.main().  This will give you the behavior you seek with just a few additional lines of code...a small additional class definition file. For example:

```
package foo.bar;

import com.example.A;

class MainEntryDelegate {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        com.example.A.main(args);
    }
}
```

So your app will then be runnable via the obvious:

```
java -cp one.jar foo.bar.MainEntryDelegate
```

or if you've set up your manifest correctly:

```
java -jar one.jar
```